# Calculate the closed formula of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, closed-form, recursion

We have the following series:

$$2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1,...$$

and so on.

Let $$x_0 = 2$$
Calculate the closed formula for $x_k$

The recursive formula for this series would be
$$x_k = x_{k−1} + x_{k−2} − {x_k−3}$$

How would I go about calculating the closed formula? Would be a division into cases, as in, if k is even x = 2, if k is odd, x = 1, be considered "closed"? This seems too easy to me. That is why I suspect "closed" might mean something else.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: $x_k=\frac{1}{2}(3+(-1)^k)$

Comment: The recurrence formula can be made more simple by $x_k=3-x_{k-1}$

Comment: Are you asking about a sequence or a series? A series is a sequence of sums. The question is not clear.

Comment: @P.Lawrence Sorry! The problem just says "series"... I don't know if this is actually what they mean or just a mistake. Would the problem even still make sense, when using the proper definition of a series? I don't understand how that would work.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Closed expression is something very very confusing, depends on the context. I would say that your solution is closed, but they probably mean that you have to consider your two cases together. Try to use what you know about the parity of $k$ using $(-1)^k.$ 
See what happens with the expression $1+(-1)^k$ for $k$ even and odd. Divide accordingly and add accordingly.